# How to print the first three lines and last two lines of a file using perl?

Tags: scripting, perl

Through the command line I draw one or several of the patterns found text.xml file:

```
perl -ln0e 'while(/<PMResult.*?<\/PMResult>/gs) {
  $x=$&;print $x if $x=~/BCCEL-[1-3]/}' text.xml
```

I need to create a new file with this pattern found; the new file will have the first three lines of Text.xml file before of pattern and have the last two lines of Text.xml file after the pattern.

Comment: Hi Guys, this is the complete command line: perl -ln0e 'while(/<PMResult.*?<\/PMResult>/gs) {$x=$&;print $x if $x=~/BCCEL-[1-3]/}' text.xml

Comment: It seems your file is XML. Use a proper parser.

Comment: ... as in one of the many available at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=xml).  For the love of God don't write another parser yourself.

Comment: @choroba, I notice that people who give this kind of advise never actually propose a solution. How do you do this with a proper parser?

Comment: Do you want the 3/2 first/last lines of the file or the 3/2 lines before/after each match (as in some context around the match)?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: With the full specification, I can show you how I would do it with a parser. I would need to see the files and understand what elements are needed.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas, I want 3/2 first/lines of the file.

Comment: What if those lines overlap with the match? Do you want to print them twice?